# PowerShell Button not clicking

Tags: powershell

I want to click this Button: (Google.com)

```
<input value="Google-Suche" aria-label="Google-Suche" name="btnK" type="submit" jsaction="sf.chk">
```

This is my code:

```
$ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.navigate("http://google.com")
Start-Sleep 5
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("lst-ib").value = $Keywords
$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "btnK"}
$Link.Click()
```

If I run it everything works fine, but it doesn't press the Button. However if I manually execute `$Link.Click()` it works.

Any idea how to fix this? Or has my Code some flaws? I am getting no Error Messages. I already trying putting a `Start-Sleep 10` before clicking the Button, but that doesn't work either.

PS: I use Google just for testing. This Code will be for another Site, but I can't Access it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sleep while ie is busy. This works for me:

```
$ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.navigate("http://google.com")
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("lst-ib").value = "cheesecake"
$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "btnK"}
$Link.Click()
```